# Sed Merge lines between two patterns inclusive first pattern but not second. with both pattern being same

Tags: sed

```
Input:
1:
aaa
bbb
2:
xxx
yyy,
zzz
3:
ccc
4:
5: 
xxx

yyy
```

Output:

```
1: aaa bbb
2: xxx yyy, zzz
3: ccc
4:
5: xxx yyy
```

Requirement: Merge all lines between pattern 1 `:$` and pattern 2 `:$` inclusive of pattern 1 but excluding pattern 2

Regex to match : `:$`
Tried:

```
sed '/:$/{n;:l N;/:$/b; s/\n/ /; bl}' | sed '/:$/!b;/:$/N;/:$/!{s/\n//g}' -E
```

Comment: Probably easier to use awk in this case. Are committed to using sed?

Answer (score 1):

With perl:

```
$ perl -0 -pe 's/\n+/ /g;
               s/ (\d+:)/\n$1/g;
               s/^\n+//;
               s/ +$/\n/' input.txt 
1: aaa bbb 
2: xxx yyy, zzz 
3: ccc 
4: 
5: xxx yyy
```

(newlines added in script for readability. It runs as-is, or you can remove them for an inscrutable  one-liner)

- first it replaces all instances of one-or-more newlines with a single space (note: this has the additional useful side-effect of deleting/ignoring empty lines).
- then it replaces the space in all instances of **a space, one-or-more digits and a `:`** with a newline.
- then it removes all leading newline(s) at the start of the string, and replaces any trailing spaces at the end of the string with a single newline. This is needed because the previous s/// substitution operations replace all newlines with a space.

The `-0` option tells perl to use NUL as the input record separator, and since the input doesn't contain any NULs, that makes it process the entire input file as one long string.

perl's `-p` option makes it work like `sed` by wrapping the entire one-liner script with a "read, process and auto-print" loop. BTW, `-n` is perl's equivalent to sed's `-n` option ("read, process but don't auto-print" loop).

See `man perlrun` for details on these `-0`, `-p`, and `-n` options.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```bash
$ awk -v ORS= '/:$/{print n; n="\n"; s=""} {print s $0; s=" "} END{print n}' ip.txt
1: aaa bbb
2: xxx yyy, zzz
3: ccc
4:
5: xxx  yyy
```

- `-v ORS=` empty value for output record separator
- `/:$/{print n; n="\n"; s=""}`

  - first time `n` will be empty (to avoid printing newline before the first line)
  - `s` is emptied everytime a match is found
- `{print s $0; s=" "}`

  - print `s` followed by the input line
  - `s` will be space character only for lines not ending with `:`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "resizable" sliding window -`$!N` is usually used together with `P` and `D` only here you need to do it on condition: accumulate lines into pattern space replacing newlines with spaces as long as the pattern space doesn't match `/:$/` otherwise print&delete up to newline and repeat:

```
sed '/:$/{
:do
$!N;/:$/{
P;D
}
s/\
/ /
t do
}' infile
```

If you prefer `gnu sed` one-liner syntax:

```
sed '/:$/{:do;$!N;/:$/{P;D;};s/\n/ /;t do}' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -Ez ':a;s/([0-9][^\n]*)\n+([[:alpha:]][^\n]*)\n+/\1 \2\n/;ta' input_file
1: aaa bbb
2: xxx yyy, zzz
3: ccc
4:
5: xxx yyy
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tr and sed is probably much easier:

```
$ tr '\n' ' ' <infile | sed 's/ [0-9]/\n&/g' | sed 's/^ //'
1: aaa bbb
2: xxx yyy zzz
3: ccc
4:
5:  xxx yyy
```

(you can even leave out the second sed in the code above if alignment is not an issue)

Comment: As soon as you do `tr '\n' ' '` you've turned your input into something that is no longer a valid text file (no terminating newline) and so YMMV with what any subsequent text processing tool does with it.